# AEM Forms upgrade JEE to OSGI

Tags: forms, aem, upgrade

Is it possible to upgrade AEM Forms **JEE v6.3** to AEM Forms **OSGi v6.5**

Answer (score 0):

A lot depends on what you mean by “upgrade”.

If you are asking if you can move your application from JEE v6.3 to OSGi v6.5 with minimal changes to the application, then it is *possible* however it is very unlikely.  Typically, most AEM Forms JEE applications make use of the AEM workflow engine (either for long-lived user processes or short-lived orchestrations).  The OSGi workflow engine is very different from the JEE one and so would require some work to translate the JEE code to OSGi.  There are lots of other things that are different too.

There is typically a fair amount of work to migrate an AEM Forms JEE application to AEM Forms OSGi.  It is however always less work that starting over from scratch on a new platform.  The basic application data models have the same heritage, so it’s usually straightforward to translate application code from JEE to AEM.  Also, the form file formats (XDPs, Adaptive Forms) are the same, so you don’t have to redesign your forms.

So, while there’s a significant amount of work to migrate, there is also a lot of existing JEE work that can be migrated to OSGi.  It is a lot of work, but a lot less work that starting over in a different product.

OSGi is typically a simpler configuration to install and maintain.  It is also where Adobe is focusing their resources, so it is a better choice for the long term.  I would recommend engaging an Adobe Gold Partner that specializes in AEM Forms to help assess the work in migrating your application to OSGi and to help guide you past the pitfalls of the migration process.